# How to get Android Maps app (version 5.0.1) source code?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am an Android developer, I need to see the Android Maps app source code. If someone has it, I would like to know where it is.. Actually, I wish to have a look the part of getting "Starred Place" list from Google server. So, the source should have it. Probably, version 5.0.1 has it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: google maps code is not open sourced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to see the Android Maps app source code

This will require several people armed with machine guns, to break into the Googleplex and try to steal it by force.

Or, as Reno points out, this is not available as open source. I am also not aware of a GData API for "starred places", though you might do some more searching to see if there is one that I missed.